# Running MsTest in Jenkins fails with CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied

Tags: jenkins, mstest

I am running MsTest as a Build Step from Jenkins but it fails with:

```
[Test] $ "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE" /resultsfile:TestResult.trx /noisolation "/testcontainer:C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Test\UnitTestProject1\bin\Debug\UnitTestProject1.dll"
Access is denied
FATAL: MSTest command execution failed
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE" (in directory "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Test"): CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied
```

I use the MsTest plugin. Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to specify the full path including executable of MSTest in your MSTest setup, currently it's trying to run "IDE" as the executable!

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Jenkins actually gave me a warning that it should be a directory when I appended MsTest but it worked afterwards.