# configuring jenkins msbuild path

Tags: jenkins, msbuild, jenkins-plugins

I have configured a new msbuild path and name
in the jenkins configure tool. The configuration pointing to v15
[image]

I receive thew following error:

> C:\jenkins_slave\cortana\workspace\xxx\testing>exit 0  FATAL:
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin doesn't exist Build step
>   'Build a Visual Studio project or solution using MSBuild' marked build
>   as failure

How can I solve it?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44071253/934407)

Comment: path to msbuild should have msbuild.exe, your setting is a folder

Comment: Here MSBuild path is depend on Vs installation , does MSBuild.exe come with jenkin plugin installation?

Answer (score 0):

In second screenshot you need to put slash at the end of the path:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\

However, to use Jenkins MSBuild plugin for VS2017 there are other things to consider. Launching MSBuild executable in my case required bunch of environment variables to be configured which otherwise are set in "Development Command Prompt".

I am contemplating using "dotnet build", "dotnet test" etc. in command line instead.